# Propagate a mount from child namespace to the parent namespace?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, linux-containers, linux-namespaces

How do I propagate a mount created in a child namespace to the parent?

## Details

I am trying to create a tool leveraging `overlayfs` for allowing writes over a read only directory. The tricky bit is that I would like any user to be able to use it without root privileges. Therefore I was hoping that this could be achieved with a mount namespace, provided an admin had mounted a directory shared, any user should then be able to create an overlay under that tree that is visible from the parent namespace (so any of the users login shells can see that overlay mount).

Here is what I tried, but is not working:

```
# admin creates a shared tree for users to mount under
sudo mkdir /overlays
# bind mount over itself with MS_REC | MS_SHARED
sudo mount --bind --rshared /overlays /overlays
```

Assuming a user then wants to create an overlay over `/some/readonly/dir`, they should create `/overlays/user/{upper,work,mnt}`. I would expect them to be able to mount an overlay under the `/overlays` dir that propagates with the following code.

```
// user_overlay.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE                                                                                                                                                                                          
#include <sched.h>                                                                                                                                                                                           

#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                           
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                          
#include <signal.h>                                                                                                                                                                                          
#include <linux/capability.h>                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <sys/mount.h>                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <sys/wait.h>                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                                                                                                          

int child(void *args)                                                                                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    pid_t p;                                                                                                                               
    p = mount("overlay", "/overlays/user/mnt", "overlay", 0, "lowerdir=/some/readonly/dir,upperdir=/overlays/user/upper,workdir=/overlays/user/work");                                                                           
    if (p == -1){                                                                                                                                                                                            
        perror("Failed to mount overlay");                                                                                                                                                                                     
        exit(1);                                                                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    // Expose the mount to the parent namespace                                                                                                                                                              
    p = mount("none", "/overlays/user/mnt", NULL, MS_SHARED, NULL);                                                                                                                                                 
    if (p == -1){                                                                                                                                                                                            
        perror("Failed to mark mount as shared");                                                                                                                                                                                     
        exit(1);                                                                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    // Exec bash so I can ensure that the mnt was created
    // though in practice I would just daemonize this proc
    // such that the mount is visible in the parent 
    // until this proc is killed
    char *newargv[] = { "/bin/bash", NULL };                                                                                                                                                                 

    execv("/bin/bash", newargv);                                                                                                                                                                             
    perror("exec");                                                                                                                                                                                          
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                                                                                                      

    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    pid_t p = clone(child, malloc(4096) + 4096, CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWUSER | SIGCHLD, NULL);                                                                                                                
    if (p == -1) {                                                                                                                                                                                           
        perror("clone");                                                                                                                                                                                     
        exit(1);                                                                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    // Wait until the bash proc in the child finishes
    waitpid(p, NULL, 0);                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return 0;                          
}
```

Executing `gcc user_overlay.c -o user_overlay && ./user_overlay` indeed mounts the overlay in that child process, but `/overlays/user/mnt` is not propagated to the parent. However modifications to `/overlays/user/upper` are visible from both parent and child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve appears to not be possible, at least not using the above method. You want to grant mounting permissions to an unprivileged user by creating a new user namespace via `CLONE_NEWUSER`. However, citing [`mount_namespaces(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) (emphasis mine):

> *Restrictions on mount namespaces*
>   Note the following points with respect to mount namespaces:
>   *  A mount namespace has an owner user namespace. **A mount namespace whose owner user namespace is different from the owner user namespace of its parent mount namespace is considered a less privileged mount namespace.**
>
> *  **When creating a less privileged mount namespace, shared mounts are    reduced to slave mounts.**  (Shared and slave mounts are discussed below.)  This ensures that mappings performed in less privileged mount namespaces will not propagate to more privileged mount namespaces.

This means that the mounts you are creating in fact have `slave` propagation type, instead of `shared` as you would expect. This results in mount events not being propagated to the parent mount namespace.